# Django Sqlite3 programming error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am very new to Django. I have created a sample project with Python v3.6 and Django V2.1. Initially, I have was using default sqlite3 database but now we have planned to change that into Mysql. For that, I have installed all the necessary plugin. On the other hand, I didn't create any table with sqlite3 except admin.

It is working fine if it was in default database when I change that into MySQL I am getting error which I can't resolve for a week :-(

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000003A93C80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 2
16, in ensure_connection

    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 1
94, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line
227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connec
t
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __
init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The speci
fied module could not be found.\r\n")      
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit_
_
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 2
16, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 1
94, in connect

    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line
227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connec
t
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __
init__
self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit_
_
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 2
16, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 1
94, in connect

    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line
227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 86, in Connec
t
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __
init__
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specifi
ed module could not be found.\r\n")

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.


Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    %config Application.verbose_crash=True

Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 780, in w
    riteout_cache
        self._writeout_input_cache(conn)
      File "C:\Users\ccduce\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\history.py", line 764, in _
    writeout_input_cache
        (self.session_number,)+line)

    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was crea
    ted in thread id 2548 and this is thread id 11036
```

Setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'shield_dev',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong with My

Comment: From where are you trying to run the Django server? How is IPython involved?

Comment: @Cyrlop I am running my Django in Window 7

Comment: Do you have db named `shield_dev` in your MYSQL?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge No, I don't have any. I have experience with Ruby on Rails so in that framework, it will automatically create DB for us. That's why I didn't create DB manually.

Comment: check your mysql db

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I have created a DB with the name `shield_dev` but still, it is not working so could you please explain in detail what I need to do from my end.

Comment: did you installed `mysqlclient` paclage ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178248/discussion-between-sethu-karthik-and-jerin-peter-george).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and proceed this way:

1. install a newer version of sqlite3 which is 3.2.0
2. delete db.sqlite3 (I did not create a new one after that)
3. `run command : python manage.py migrate`
4. `python manage.py runserver`
5. `python manage.py createsuperuser`
6. log in then add new user or add something in a model table.

Good luck